# Filtering a gridview without querying the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to filter a gridview using a selected item from the dropdownlist. It's easily done with sql queries but how can I do it without querying the database. For example in the code below. I am filtering by Industry. If in the DDL the industry selected is "Technology" I only want the data in the Technology Industry. Industry is a column name in the gridview.

```
   protected void Industry_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string ddlItem = DropDownListFilterIndustry.SelectedItem.Text; //Get the dropdownlist value
            DataTable dt = ViewState["GridViewTable"] as DataTable; //get the viewstate of the gridview

            string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() //get columns
                                 .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                                 .ToArray();

            GridViewScreener.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewScreener.DataBind();
     }
```

Comment: Use a DataView ? As per the following link http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

Comment: I was just googling about that. Let me try it later. Cheers

Comment: @cloudviz - Can you share the gridview markup? Also I am confused you want to filter the rows or columns? It should be rows right? ;)

Comment: @Rahul Industry is the column name. Technology, Banks, Healthcare are the rows/items. On my way to work now, Can't paste the markup at the moment. Cheers.